# Using externalIP as a service in kubernetes for on premise with network load balancer

Tags: kubernetes

I have 3 nodes k8 cluster in on-premise setup in my company which run a TCP listener exposed on port `58047`.

We have a network load balancer which can RR on this nodes.

I can expose the port to the host in each nodes so NLB will take care, or should i create a service which exposes a single external ip which will be specified in the NLB.

Which is the best approach?

```
NAME                                    READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
pod/iothubdeployment-57bbb5f4d6-m62df   1/1     Running   1          50m
pod/iothubdeployment-57bbb5f4d6-r9mzr   1/1     Running   1          50m
pod/iothubdeployment-57bbb5f4d6-w5dq4   1/1     Running   0          50m

NAME                 TYPE        CLUSTER-IP   EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)   AGE
service/kubernetes   ClusterIP   10.96.0.1    <none>        443/TCP   5d18h

NAME                               READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
deployment.apps/iothubdeployment   3/3     3            3           56m

NAME                                          DESIRED   CURRENT   READY   AGE
replicaset.apps/iothubdeployment-57bbb5f4d6   3         3         3       50m
replicaset.apps/iothubdeployment-6b78b96dc5   0         0         0       56m
```

My deployment-definition

```
apiVersion: apps/v1 
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: iothubdeployment
spec:
  replicas: 3
  strategy:
    type: RollingUpdate
    rollingUpdate:
      maxSurge: 1
      maxUnavailable: 67%
  minReadySeconds: 5
  selector:
    matchLabels:
     app: iothub
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: iothub
        version: 1.1.0
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: iothubpod
          image: gitlab.dt.local:5555/cere-brum/iot_gateway/iot_hub/iot_hub:latest
          imagePullPolicy: Always
          ports:
          - containerPort: 58047
            hostPort: 58000
            protocol: TCP
      imagePullSecrets:
        - name: regcred
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you’re directly trying to expose a Deployment via a host port. That is not recommended: you should create a Service that instructs Kubernetes how to expose your Deployment to other workloads in the cluster and outside.

A NodePort service would allow you to properly expose your Deployment on each Node: your load balancer can then be configured to connect to that port on any of your *node* IPs.